# Magento2 Plugin for beforeExceute that return a $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

I've to "override" a module that manage a redirect.
The original module have this code:

```
public function execute()
    {
            [...]
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
            [...]
    }
```

How can i modifiy that result?
I'm trying to create a plugin with an after method, but i'm not sure that i can works.

```
<?php

namespace ACME\MODULE\Plugin\Original;

class Login{

    public function afterExecute(\Bla\Bla\Controller\Original\Login $subject, $result){
// What i've to put down here?

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your afterExecute ? Redirect or on other link or do some stuff and keep the original redirect ?